# contentToString is deprecated in kotlin 1.4, what is the alternative?

Tags: kotlin

I have been using `contentToString` method in kotlin to print the content of an array but after upgrading the kotlin version to 1.4, I am getting deprecation warning for this method, I looked through the documentation but could not find the alternative for this method. Does anybody what we are supposed to use in place of contentToString to print the content of an array ?

Comment: Couldn't you use something like a `forEach`? `someList.forEach(System.out::print)`

Comment: Sure I can, but it's cumbersome. `contentToString` is more elegant and quick especially for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Kotlin plugin version to 1.4 in the IDE, then deprecation warning will disappear

Comment: There is no update. I am using the most udpated version of the plugin and my IntelliJ idea is also updated(2020.2)

Comment: @Ezio use Early Access Preview 1.4.x in Setting > Languages & Frameforks > Kotlin > Update channel until they released a stable version

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the question.  The function is deprecated, what is one supposed to use instead of it?